# Is it possible to access system keychain in iOS?

Tags: ios, keychain

Is it possible to access system keychain in iOS? I tried contacting the developer of https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain but haven't got a reply. This library seems to do that but Apple docs say it is not possible and that only app-specific keychains can be accessed? Has anyone else tried this library and is it possible?

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: please tell me where you find docs about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as per the official documentation, its not possible and even if some using low level  libraries to provide such functionality it may work on jail broken phones but you cant launch your app .Apple store will reject the app simply.

Comment: @AndreyM. Here is another one about the keychain sharing between apps. Hope it will give you the needed info.

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-12-dumping-keychain-data/#gref

Official Doc: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3